# Pytest with selenium. How to pytest a function that calls another function to keep the code going?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a small python script that uses selenium to login to a url, verify user is logged in and then add a new user. I managed to pytest the first function named autologin(). The issue is , at the end of the function I call my next function which is AutoCreateUser(). So when I write a pytest for AutoCreateUser, it obviously fails cause the pytest just jumps right into the Autocreateuser function. How can I handle this in pytest?

This is my main code.

```
class AutoBot:
    def __init__(self):
        chrome_driver_path = "chromedriver.exe"
        service = ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service) #init chrome driver and assign self to call it from anywhere
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        
        with open(root / 'Records.json', 'r') as rf: #open json and decode data inside
            decoded_data = json.load(rf) 

        login = decoded_data['Login'] #login 
        #some json decoded data

        #xpath for website
        HTMLXPath = decoded_data['HTMLXPath'] 
        #some html elements here
 
        #login variables
        self.Username = username
        self.password = password
        self.URL = HrmUrl

        self.AutoLogin()

    def AutoLogin(self):
        self.driver.get(self.URL)
        #some code to navigate through the url and login
  
        #once done go to the next function
        self.AutoCreateUser()

    def AutoCreateUser(self):
        
        print("Attempting to add Employee")
        #some  code and go to next function and so on
```

This is my pytest code. The test_autologin function works, just the second function obviously fails. How can I handle this? I found something regarding mock, but unsure how I would implement it here.

```
from mymaincode import AutoBot
class TestAutoBot:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def autobot(self):
        bot = AutoBot()
        yield bot
        bot.driver.quit()

    def test_autologin(self, autobot):
        autobot.AutoLogin()
        WebDriverWait(autobot.driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, autobot.logout_xpath))
        )
        assert autobot.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, autobot.logout_xpath).is_displayed(), "Login failed!"
        

    def test_auto_createuser(self,autobot):
        autobot.AutoCreateUser()
        WebDriverWait(autobot.driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, autobot.logout_xpath))
        )
        assert autobot.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'section-data').is_displayed(), "Error"
```